# UPDATE using subqueries - Updates more than the needed records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day everyone. I would like to ask a question regarding my SQL statement. I am using SQL Server 2008 and has a table called Workflow Transaction. In this table, I have 12 records. The picture below is the content of the table.

[image]

I have this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE Workflow_Txn 
SET Status = 1
WHERE [RequestId] IN
(
    SELECT [RequestId]
    FROM Workflow_Txn 
    WHERE [OrderNumber] < (SELECT MAX(OrderNumber) FROM Workflow_Txn WHERE RequestId = 3)      
    AND RequestId = 3
)
```

My objective is to update a request ID that has the OrderNumber of less than the maximum, which will be the output from the SELECT statement inside the WHERE clause. Now I expect that the records to be updated shall be only the said records (in the code, it's RequestId # 3).

What actually happened was instead of only four records being updated, it becomes five (5)! Is there a problem with my existing SQL statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you're doing an update of ALL records with RequestId = 3. Take into account that your subquery result is `3` so you end up updating all related records.

Your query is equivalent to do

```
UPDATE Workflow_Txn 
SET Status = 1
WHERE RequestId = 3
```

Not sure if you have any reason to make your query more complex than it needs to be. Seems to me that something simpler would do the trick

```
UPDATE Workflow_Txn 
SET    Status = 1
WHERE  [OrderNumber] < (SELECT MAX(OrderNumber) FROM Workflow_Txn WHERE RequestId = 3)      
       AND RequestId = 3
```

Comment: I think what you have shown me was simpler than mine. I am aiming at updating the records lower than the order number, i.e. I would update the records before the latest record.

Comment: @Ju-chan: As far as I understand my query should work, have you tested it?

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your query is that the subquery goes into great detail to find the records with order number less than the maximum.  And then it chooses everything with the same request -- which would include the maximum order number.

I prefer to fix this using a CTE as follows:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             MAX(OrderNumber) as MaxON
      from Workflow_txn
      where RequestId = 3
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET Status = 1
    where OrderNumber < MaxON;
```

I like this structure, because I can run the CTE separately to see what records are likely to be updated.

To fix your query, you would change the request to using `OrderNumber` and repeat the `RequestId = 3`:

```
UPDATE Workflow_Txn 
SET Status = 1
WHERE [RequestId] = 3 and
      OrderNumber in
(
    SELECT [OrderNumber]
    FROM Workflow_Txn 
    WHERE [OrderNumber] < (SELECT MAX(OrderNumber) FROM Workflow_Txn WHERE RequestId = 3)      
    AND RequestId = 3
)
```

Comment: I like the simpler way too (although I prefer my first method for the reasons given in the solution).  However, I believe that @StuartAinsworth answered with the simplified version first -- which is why I upvoted his answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your subquery just said to return RequestID of 3, so you updated all of the requests with that ID; walk it through.  What I think you were looking for was something like:

```
UPDATE Workflow_Txn 
SET Status = 1
WHERE [RequestId] = 3
AND  [OrderNumber] < (SELECT MAX(OrderNumber) FROM Workflow_Txn WHERE RequestId = 3)
```